# React / Redux / Send text typed on textarea to the store

Tags: reactjs, redux

my action:

```
export const ON_MESSAGE = 'ON_MESSAGE';

export const sendMessage = (text, sender = 'user') => ({
  type: ON_MESSAGE,
  payload: { text, sender },
});
```

my reducer:

```
const initalState = [{ text: [] }];

const messageReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_MESSAGE:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default messageReducer;
```

my code:

```
const Chat = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const messages = useSelector(state => state.Chat);

  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <Styled.ChatHeader>
        <p>Chat Bot</p>
        <div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} size="1x" color="white" />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} size="1x" color="white" />
        </div>
      </Styled.ChatHeader>
      <Styled.ChatLog></Styled.ChatLog>
      <Styled.ChatInput>
        <textarea placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem" />
        <button onClick={dispatch(sendMessage)}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} size="lg" color="black" />
        </button>
      </Styled.ChatInput>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};

export { Chat };
```

Hello basically i would like to know how i would send the value typed in my text to my redux store

and also how I would display this typed value in my component

```
> <Styled.ChatLog> </ Styled.ChatLog>
```

basically each message should generate a div (a component)

```
> <Styled.ChatMessage />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store your message in local state and send that to payload.

```
const Chat = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const messages = useSelector(state => state.Chat);
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <Styled.ChatHeader>
        <p>Chat Bot</p>
        <div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} size="1x" color="white" />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} size="1x" color="white" />
        </div>
      </Styled.ChatHeader>
      <Styled.ChatLog>
        {messages.map( message => (
          <Styled.ChatMessage>
            {message.text}
          </Styled.ChatMessage>
        )}
      </Styled.ChatLog>
      <Styled.ChatInput>
        <textarea value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem" />
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(sendMessage({ text }))}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} size="lg" color="black" />
        </button>
      </Styled.ChatInput>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};

export { Chat };
```

Comment: i got this error on   <button onClick={dispatch(sendMessage({ text }))}>: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: updated answer, you need to create arrow function there () => dispatch(sendMessage( { text })

Comment: Thanks bro could you help me what better way to show the typed messages in my ChatMessage component on chatlog

Comment: you can map over your messages and render your ChatMessage component. I updated my answer. please check

Comment: i got this error : ×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: my bad you need to render {message.text} inside ChatMessage. updated code

Comment: now the error is after I click send kk
I have these errors:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
and:
he above error occurred in the <div> component:
and:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text}).

Comment: this is my structure messages: 0: {text: Array(0)}
1: {text: {…}, sender: "user"}

Comment: Can you please create new question with all information?

Comment: Can you please create new question with all information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206972/discussion-between-amit-chauhan-and-gabriel).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004922/react-js-and-redux-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child